# How do I return an attribute of a node that is related to the node I am matching?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to query the following:

List Names of students and their mentors.

[Image of the schema for my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q1Lt.png)

I am using the following query:

```
MATCH (mName:Faculty)-[:Mentors]->(sName:Student) RETURN sName,mName
```

But when I run it, I get the salary of the mentor and the classification of the student. I want to have the name of each.  I tried this:

```
MATCH (mName:Faculty)-[:Mentors]->(sName:Student)<-[:S2P]-(person) RETURN person.Name,mName
```

But that had a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dividing personal information into its own node, and I don't think that will be best way to model this in a graph db. I'd recommend consolidating that data into your :Student and :Faculty nodes, though you can add the :Person label onto both of them so you can treat them as :Persons in other queries.

With your current model, this query should work:

```
MATCH (facultyPerson)<-[:F2P]-(:Faculty)-[:Mentors]->(:Student)-[:S2P]->(studentPerson) 
RETURN facultyPerson.Name as faculty, studentPerson.Name as student
```

If you want to collect student names under each faculty person, you can use COLLECT():

```
MATCH (facultyPerson)<-[:F2P]-(:Faculty)-[:Mentors]->(:Student)-[:S2P]->(studentPerson) 
RETURN facultyPerson.Name as faculty, collect(studentPerson.Name) as students
```

And if you consolidated your node data so name, address, and dob are properties of each :Faculty and :Student, your query becomes:

```
MATCH (fac:Faculty)-[:Mentors]->(student:Student)
RETURN fac.Name as faculty, collect(student.Name) as students
```

Also, I'd recommend using camel case for property names.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The second one is exactly what I was looking for!